# JSF and PrimeFaces: launching and stopping javascript 'indeterminate dialog' via

Tags: javascript, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces, dialog

The problem is, I have next to no knowledge of javascript, and just a passing knowledge of PrimeFaces, and I couldn't find how-to in the documentation :(

So I have a primefaces text box on my page:

```
<p:inputText styleClass="step1-input" value="#{PageBean.documentToDownload}">
    <p:ajax event="keyup" update="infopanel,infopanel2,downloadbutton" listener="#{PageBean.validateUrl}"/>
</p:inputText>
```

In the text box, when I write something, an action takes place, which takes a few seconds to complete. On result, a `panel` appears on the page that either displays something, or says what I've written is wrong:

```
<p:panel id="infopanel" visible="#{PageBean.validLink and PageBean.info != null}" header="Information" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
    <h:outputText value="Everything is okay"/>   
</p:panel>
<p:panel  id="infopanel2" visible="#{PageBean.validLink and PageBean.info == null}" header="Error" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
    <h:outputText value="An undefined error occured."/>
</p:panel>
```

There's already a primefaces `statusDialog` on the page that I can use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function start(){ statusDialog.show(); }
    function stop(){ statusDialog.hide(); }
</script>
```

So, what I want to do is: on `keyup` event in the input text I want to launch `start()` function, to display a `dialog`, only if `PageBean.validLink` is true (`validLink` is set in `PageBean.validateUrl` listener, and it's instantaneous)
And when `infopanel` or `infopanel2` is shown as an ajax action, I want to call the `stop()` function.

So, how can I do that?

Comment: What does the `dialog` do ? Does it display the messages from your `panel` ? Also, when you use `keyup`, `start()` will be called regardless of the condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly you want to execute javascript function when the ajax action completes? For this you can use the oncomplete attribute on the ajax component:

```
<p:ajax event="keyup" update="infopanel,infopanel2,downloadbutton" listener {PageBean.validateUrl}" oncomplete="stop()"/>
```

If you want to make a callback to execute before an ajax reques begins, you can use the onstart attribute